# Java - GregorianCalendar outputting wrong year?

Tags: java, date

When I instantiate a new date using GregorianCalendar like this:

```
GregorianCalendar myCal = new GregorianCalendar(29,5,2011);
```

Then, finally, I carry out the following code (expecting it to return 2011), and it returns 35. I'm wondering why this is, as I will need to compare it to the passed date (2011).

```
System.out.println(myCal.get(Calendar.YEAR));
```

Answer (score 5):

Are you even reading the [documentation](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/util/GregorianCalendar.html#GregorianCalendar%28int,%20int,%20int%29)/method signatures?

```
public GregorianCalendar(int year, int month, int dayOfMonth)
```

Try this:

```
GregorianCalendar myCal = new GregorianCalendar(2011, Calendar.MAY, 29);
```

And BTW: 5th month is actually June, I guess you wanted May (months are 0-based). To avoid confusion use constants like `Calendar.MAY` (equal to 4...)

Answer (score 0):

The `GregorianCalendar` constructor you are using does not expect dayOfMonth, month, year as arguments, but year, month, dayOfMonth. See the [JavaDoc](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/6/docs/api/java/util/GregorianCalendar.html#GregorianCalendar%28int,%20int,%20int%29) for details.